# text-align rule does not work as expected

Tags: html, css, text-align

```css
.shrink-side-bar{
    width: 5%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: aqua;
}
    
.shrink-icon{
    width:38px;
    height: 50px;
    margin-left: -152%;
    margin-top: 54%;
}
    
li img {
    text-align: center;
}

.shrink-menu{
    list-style: none;    
}

li i {
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<body>
    <div id="shrink-side-bar" class="shrink-side-bar">
        <ul class="shrink-menu">
            <li><img class="shrink-icon" src="img/logo%20tkb.png"></li>
            <li><i class="fa fa-sun-o"></i></li>
            <li><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i></li>
            <li><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></li>
            <li><i class="fa fa-file-code-o"></i></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

In the code above I'm trying to align the icons on the middle of the aqua bar, but it is not working as expected. Can any one help me fix this bug? The `text-align` rule is in `li a` selector.

Comment: I don't see an `li a` CSS rule nor `li a` applicable elements

Comment: i got the answer..please remember that we can accept an answer just after 15 mints after asking the question. OK ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.shrink-side-bar{
      width: 5%;
      height: 100%;
      background-color: aqua;
     
  }
  .shrink-icon{
      width:38px;
      height: 50px;
      
      
  }

  .shrink-menu{
      list-style: none;
      text-align: center;
      /*margin: auto;    */
      padding: 0
  }

  li img{
      text-align: center;
  }

li i{
  text-align: center;
  /*margin: auto;*/
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div id="shrink-side-bar" class="shrink-side-bar">
    <ul class="shrink-menu">
        <li><img class="shrink-icon" src="img/logo%20tkb.png"></li>
        <li><i class=" fa fa-sun-o"></i></li>
        <li><i class=" fa fa-envelope-o"></i></li>
        <li><i class=" fa fa-chevron-right"></i></li>
        <li><i class=" fa fa-file-code-o"></i></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to take the padding off of the "shrink-menu" and then set text alignment on the list item like this...

```css
.shrink-side-bar{
        width: 5%;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: aqua;
       
    }
    .shrink-icon{
        width:38px;
        height: 50px;
        margin-left: -152%;
        margin-top: 54%;
        
        
    }
    li img{
        text-align: center;
    }
    .shrink-menu{
        list-style: none;
        padding: 0;    
    }
li {
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<body>
        <div id="shrink-side-bar" class="shrink-side-bar">
            <ul class="shrink-menu">
                <li><img class="shrink-icon" src="img/logo%20tkb.png"></li>
                <li><i class=" fa fa-sun-o"></i></li>
                <li><i class=" fa fa-envelope-o"></i></li>
                <li><i class=" fa fa-chevron-right"></i></li>
                <li><i class=" fa fa-file-code-o"></i></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

In

```
li i{
position:relative;
  left:-30px;
}
```

```css
.shrink-side-bar{
        width: 5%;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: aqua;
       
    }
    .shrink-icon{
        width:38px;
        height: 50px;
        margin-left: -152%;
        margin-top: 54%;
        
        
    }
    li img{
        text-align: center;
    }
    .shrink-menu{
        list-style: none;    
    }
li i{
    text-align: center;
  position:relative;
  left:-30px;
  top:-20px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<body>
        <div id="shrink-side-bar" class="shrink-side-bar">
            <ul class="shrink-menu">
                <li><img class="shrink-icon" src="img/logo%20tkb.png"></li>
                <li><i class=" fa fa-sun-o"></i></li>
                <li><i class=" fa fa-envelope-o"></i></li>
                <li><i class=" fa fa-chevron-right"></i></li>
                <li><i class=" fa fa-file-code-o"></i></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what you actually want but i think by changing this will solve your problem

```
.shrink-icon {
        padding: 12px;
        width: 100%;
        height: 10%;
        margin-left: -13px;
        margin-top: 54%;
    }
```